# Starting Mutliple Rails Servers in one bash command in their own tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I'm kind of a crazy person with bash shortcuts.  Right now my team and I start our servers with the following shortcuts: www, admin, api.  I was hoping to automate the start of all these in one simple bash command (that opens new tabs for each server).

We're on OS X so this is pretty easy to do if the commands were run as daemons (which they are not).

```
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gp='git push'
alias gs='git status'
alias b="bundle"
alias www="cd $HOME && cd code/www && rails s webrick"
alias admin='cd $HOME && cd code/admin && rails s -p 3003'
alias api='cd $HOME && cd code/api && rails s -p 3002'


start-all () {
  www
  osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "api" in selected tab of the front window'
}
```

You can see the start-all function is very close. This will use the OSASCRIPT to open new tabs and run bash commands in new bash tabs, however since the servers aren't starting daemons the bash doesn't know to execute the next line of code.

I'd rather not run these servers as daemons for a few reasons, so I was hoping someone who knows bash/os x better can assist!

Comment: Anyone mind commenting why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

```
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gp='git push'
alias gs='git status'
alias b="bundle"
alias www="cd $HOME && cd code/www && rails s webrick > server1.out 2>&1 &"
alias admin='cd $HOME && cd code/admin && rails s -p 3003  > server2.out 2>&1 &'
alias api='cd $HOME && cd code/api && rails s -p 3002  > server3.out 2>&1 &'


start-all () {
  www
  osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "api" in selected tab of the front window'
}
```

you can try them and output it to corresponding logs too